# Laravel get recently created related models without using with or load

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a specific issue where I am creating a related model as such:

```
$detail = new \App\Detail
$detail->item = "Soda Pop"
$detail->quantity += 1
$order->details()->save($detail)
```

This code is within a **foreach statement**, and I end up creating a detail for each item purchased. But I have a specific requirement that if an item already exists in the details list, then add *+1* to it.

But on the save the relationship, I don't have access to the objects and it forces me to reload from the database. So either I have to perform a `$order->load('details')` to make the code work.

Is there any way I can access the recently created object and just check from memory if it was inserted?

Comment: Can you show the foreach you are currently using?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the updateOrCreate Method

```php
$detail = App\Detail::updateOrCreate(
    ['order_id' => $order-id, 'item' => 'Soda Pop'],[]
);

$detail->quantity += 1;

$detail = $detail->update();
```

Comment: Yes, and it does not find it. I have to forcefully load the relationship after each save or before each check.

Comment: i am assuming your details table has an order_id right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [firstOrNew](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#other-creation-methods):

```
$detail = $order->details()->firstOrNew(['item' => 'Soda Pop']);

$detail->quantity += 1;

$detail->save();
```